# Access 2007 - Building unmatched data query, but need two field categories

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is it possible to build an unmatched data query using two tables with a tracking a unique value field and also another value in the row as well (that value will not be unique).

For example I want to track a unique customer code from an invoice on a new table, compared to last month's invoice. The non unique value would be a "product code" of what they purchased.

A customer code could appear multiple times depending on if they have purchased multiple product codes.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you wanting to match just on customer code or the combination of customer code and product code?

Comment: Both the customer code and product code. 

Ideally I would be able to "bounce" table 1 off of table 1 to get all of the new customers for the new month and also if any customers that were on last months invoice bought a new product this month.

Comment: 2 tables. Basically 1 representing last month's invoice and 1 representing this month's.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
SELECT Invoice.CustomerID
FROM Invoice LEFT JOIN PreviousInvoices
     ON (Invoice.Product = PreviousInvoices.Product) 
    AND (Invoice.CustomerID = PreviousInvoices.CustomerID)
WHERE PreviousInvoices.Product Is Null
```